# Why linux pipes and stdout from exec not working together?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

Im writing code with linux pipes and dont understand, why only printfs (1) or only exec (2) goes to input of parent process. If I comment exec, than printf work fine. If uncomment, only "ls" output shown

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd[2], pid;
    if (pipe(fd) != 0) return 1;
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) return 1;
    if (pid == 0) // child
    {
        close( STDOUT_FILENO );
        dup2( fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO );

        close( fd[0] );
        close( fd[1] ); // */

        printf( "hello\n" ); // (1)
        printf( "hello2\n" );

        // execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", NULL ); // (2)

        printf( "exec not executed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        close( STDIN_FILENO );
        dup2( fd[0], STDIN_FILENO );

        close( fd[0] );
        close( fd[1] );

        char buf[100];

        while( gets( buf ) != NULL )
            printf( "message: %s\n", buf );
    }
}
```

output when exec commented:

> message: hello
>   message: hello2 
>   message: exec not executed

when exec not commented:

> message: filt1
>   message: filt1.d
>   *.... other files*
>   message: makefile
>   message: objects.mk

Comment: Please show the exact output of your program for each case. It's not clear what "only exec (2) goes to input of parent process" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, stdio fully buffers output to a stream unless it's writing to a terminal (except for `stderr`, which is unbuffered). So the output to the pipe is being buffered.

When you call `execl()`, the memory of the current process is discarded and replaced with the program you're loading. This causes the stdio output buffers to be discarded, so they never get written to the pipe.

The simple solution is to call `fflush(stdout);` before calling `execl()`.

Comment: Yes, its really buffering :)
Added fflush and got all messages from printf and exec.
Thanks!